# How can I use the docker daemon from a container running on a host provisioned by Docker Machine?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am trying to use the docker daemon from a container on a host created by docker machine.

Initially I was trying to connect to the host daemon via a volume-mounted unix socket (`-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`), but that kept failing:

```
[root@f57377672f7f docker]# env | grep DOCKER
DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/etc/docker

[root@bd4154b372d5 code]# docker images
An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.23/images/json: tls: oversized record received with length 20527
```

I'm not sure why it's trying to connect over HTTPS even though `DOCKER_HOST` is `unix://`.

---

Next I tried `tcp://`, but this failed because the TLS certs generated by docker machine are generated to work only for the host's external interfaces.

```
# On the host
ubuntu@spot:~$ ps aux | grep 'docker daemon'
root     23678  0.4  0.7 907564 59648 ?        Ssl  10:01   1:16 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --storage-driver aufs --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert /etc/docker/server.pem --tlskey /etc/docker/server-key.pem --label provider=amazonec2

# From the container
[root@f57377672f7f docker]# env | grep DOCKER
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.17.0.1:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/etc/docker

[root@f57377672f7f docker]# docker images
An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://172.17.0.1:2376/v1.23/images/json: x509: certificate is valid for 54.165.194.148, not 172.17.0.1
```

Thus, in order to connect to the host's daemon from a container, I need to:

1. Copy the certs from my local `~/.docker/machines/machine/$machine/` to the container at build-time.
2. Hard-wire the external IP of that host as `DOCKER_HOST` (eg. `tcp://54.165.194.148:2376`) in the container at build-time, too.

Is there a way to get around this with without turning TLS off on the external interface? I also don't want to modify my the container's `Dockerfile` for every host that it has to run on.

Answer (score -1):

The docker client only attempts HTTPS connections if `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` is enabled or even set in the environment. It attempts to translate the `DOCKER_HOST` URI to an `https://` address.

To allow the client to use a local socket instead of HTTPS, you must first set `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY`

```
[root@f57377672f7f docker]# unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
```

`docker [command]` works over the unix socket!

Comment: You don't actually have to set any of those environment variables- using the socket is the default behavior for the docker client, and the certs don't apply over the socket.  Just mount the volume, make sure your container is --priviliged, and proceed.

Comment: @PaulBecotte yep, found that out after wasting a bunch of time. I do need the `DOCKER_HOST` env var though because I am using a tool that reads it (`spotify/docker-maven-plugin`)